# Is there any way to get a list of Wi-Fi networks other than the deprecated WifiManager.startScan() method?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, wifimanager

Maybe someone here can help me - I'm developing an app and I want the user to be able to choose a Wi-Fi network, and in order to make it easier for them I wanted to show a list of all available networks or all networks they have remembered on their device. The way I'm currently doing it is with this method:

WifiManager.startScan()

which is deprecated in API level 28 (here's the [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager)).
My question is if there's a different way to get a list of either all available Wi-Fi networks (by performing a scan similarly to this method) or all Wi-Fi networks remembered on the device (something which I wasn't able to find anywhere)
thanks!